# Mongoose creating Database without any Record/document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-atlas

I read in official documentation on MongoDB that

> MongoDB only creates the database when you first store data in that database.

I created database using mongosh and found it to be true. Now I am trying to create database using `mongoose` module in Nodejs. I am just creating database and not adding any records.
This is my code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const itemadd = require("./model/schema.js")   // Js file having schema 

async function start()
{
    try {
        
      await  mongoose.connect(process.env.mongo_uri)   // line ABC 
        console.log("We are successful")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("We encountered an error :-\n",error)
    }

}

start();
```

Now in this piece of code I am just connecting to my server at atlas in `line ABC`. However upon checking the atlas I am seeing that the database has been created with collection inside it (collection name as per given in schema). Although there is no document/record in it , but still database has been created.
Can anyone tell me how without any record, database was created.

Comment: In MongoDB, a database is automatically created when data is first written to it. This means that when you define a new collection in your Mongoose schema and connect to your MongoDB server using `mongoose.connect()`, Mongoose will create a new database with the given name and collection inside it, even if no documents are inserted into the collection.